# ¿Por qué no localiza mi controlador mi archivo index?

Tags: php

Tengo el `index.php` con las siguientes líneas de código

```
namespace app\controllers;
$class = new Inicio();
$class->Index();
```

Y el error que me muestra es

> Uncaught Error: Class 'app\controllers\Inicio' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ClínicaVeterinaria\index.php:4

Comment: En tu proyecto. Cuál es la ruta de tu clase **Inicio**?

Comment: ClínicaVeterinaria(raíz)/app/controllers/'NombreControlador.php'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder a una clase que se encuentra dentro del alcance de un namespace específico, deberás hacer lo siguiente:

```
use app\controllers\Inicio;
```

Y ahora deberías poder acceder a dicha clase:

```
$class = new Inicio();
```

No olvides el uso de `require 'archivoOrigen.php'` para indicar de donde obtendrá dicha clase, al inicio de tu archivo.

- La instrucción `require 'archivodelaClase.php'` sirve para invocar el origen de la clase, es decir el archivo donde fue escrita
- La keyword `use` sirve para indicar que namespace y eventualmente que clase vamos a usar.

**Notas**

- Cuando tu escribes `namespace app\controllers;` en realidad lo que estás haciendo es declarar el ámbito dentro del cual estará declarado un bloque de código, dicho eso se aclara que así no estás invocando el *namespace*.
- Para el caso donde necesitas ocupar la clase `Inicio` que esta dentro del *namespace* en cuestión se cambia el uso de `namespace` por el de `use`.

Comment: Me arroja el mismo error sólo que con la ruta 'app\controllers\Inicio\Inicio'

Comment: Revisa la edición @AlbertoAsencio

Comment: @Aprendiz, estoy casi seguro que el problema continuará, aún con tu nueva sugerencia... el problema es otro (supongo). O bueno, al menos no sé en dónde está esa clase de **Inicio** pero escribir un **use** no creo que lo solucione, igual antes no la encontraba.

Comment: el detalle es que desde el archivo que trata de usar la clase `Inicio` debe usar la sintaxis de `use` para invocarlo, mientras que como el lo esta haciendo es para declarar un namespace y las clases que tendrá en su contexto, además se me pasaba el detalle de requierir el archivo; por ejemplo usando `require 'archivo.php'` @PakLei